# Same XmlElements with different names

Tags: java, jaxb

I have XML structure like this:

```
<page>
  <lang>
    <fr>La météo de la semaine</fr>
    <en>This week’s weather</en>
    <l code="de">Wetter Woche</l>
  </lang>
</page>
```

Message duplicated on various languages. Each alternative is enclosed in a  element labeled with a ISO-639 language code. For convenience, `<da>, <de>`  can be used in place of `<l code="da">, <l code="de">`. 
  I don't want  define a field in lang class  for each language, of course.  Is it possible? Note: I don't want use any jaxb extension, like  EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy), but I will be grateful to any advice.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I explained so ambiguously.  I mean, what should I do to match this XML structure and don't write class member for  each alternative?

Answer (score 2):

I believe I know what you are asking.  You want to turn this XML into a Java class object populated with each language and language content.  However, you do not want to have a million different member variables, one for each language.

What I recommend is a Map object that pairs language prefixes with the content of each language.  Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html if you are unfamiliar with Maps.

Using this approach you can use whatever parsing strategy you are using to create a new key-value pair for each tag-content pair in your XML.